# Stale exception even using static lock method

Tags: grails, groovy, concurrency, grails-orm

I am not new to hibernate, concurrrency problems, and stale exceptions.

Im working in grails with GORM in a high concurrent environment. Optimistic locking is on and im using static lock method whithin a transactional service.

```
        for(Entity entity : entityList) {
            //refresh and lock for update
            entity.refresh();
            entity = Entity.lock(entity.id)
            entity.setSomeData(new Date());
            entity.save()
        }
```

It is somehow possible to have an HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException in this scenario??

Please note the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.xxxxx.xxx.xxxxx.Entity#48225]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.lock.PessimisticWriteSelectLockingStrategy.lock(PessimisticWriteSelectLockingStrategy.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.lock(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1954)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractLockUpgradeEventListener.upgradeLock(AbstractLockUpgradeEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSessionCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.lockAndLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2544)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1023)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate$5.doInHibernate(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:179)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.lock(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:279)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.lock(HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:221)
    at com.xxxxx.xxx.xxxxx.Entity.lock(Entity.groovy)
```

How is possible for static Entity.lock() to throw a stale object exception??

Comment: imho the message says, that the row representing the object in your database is missing. That could for example means that entity.id has a wrong value. Is it possible, that in your highly concurrent environment entityList contains entities,  which don't exist anymore?

Comment: This exception is thrown when the database is unable to lock the row in question i.e. if there's no Entity id 48225 in the database. The way it works it tries to do `select ...from Entity where id = 48225 for update`. When it returns no rows a `StaleObjectStateException` is thrown.

Comment: AS long as i know stale object is thrown when object in session is is not equal to object in BBDD. This happens e.g. when we try to save an objecy but another thread from another session (probably another node) has already updated the BBDD. Ive never seen this exception rased when record is not found ... are you sure about it? ... can you link me to any place where this behavior is documented?

Comment: In other hand i am sure that object exists when this method is called because is an update operation for an existing entity ... and we do not delete this kind of objects from the database.